# Get only Oracle function return table's columns and their types

Tags: c#, oracle

Is there an oracle query which I can use to get back the details of an oracle function which returns a table, where I'm looking for the info of that table, say the record name, but mostly the columns in that record and their types.

Example function:

```
create or replace
function return_table return t_nested_table AS

v_ret   t_nested_table;

begin
  v_ret  := t_nested_table();

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(1, 'one');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(2, 'two');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(3, 'three');

  return v_ret;
end return_table;
```

using type

```
create or replace
type t_col as object (
  i number,
  n varchar2(30)
);
create or replace
type t_nested_table as table of t_col;
```

Knowing only the owner (system) and object name (return_table), I want to execute a query which will return for me the info of t_col.
The names (i, n) and types (number, varchar2) of the columns

I can't just execute the query by itself cause there might be scenarios where there are required inputs for that function which won't be known at the time when I'm trying to only get the column info

I'll be executing this query in C# .Net

Comment: I think that you can join system views: [all_arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1014.htm#REFRN20015) and [all_type_attrs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2109.htm#REFRN20295).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current login, use

```
SELECT uta.attr_name, uta.attr_type_name || CASE WHEN uta.length IS NOT NULL THEN '('||uta.length||')' ELSE NULL END 
  FROM user_coll_types uct
  JOIN user_type_attrs uta 
    ON uta.type_name = uct.elem_type_name
 WHERE uct.type_name = 'COLLECTION_NAME'
 ORDER BY uta.attr_no;
```

For the logged in user having access on types from another users:

```
SELECT ata.attr_name, ata.attr_type_name || CASE WHEN ata.length IS NOT NULL THEN '('||ata.length||')' ELSE NULL END 
  FROM all_coll_types act
  JOIN all_type_attrs ata 
    ON ata.type_name = act.elem_type_name AND ata.OWNER = act.OWNER
 WHERE act.type_name = 'COLLECTION_NAME'
   AND act.OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME'
 ORDER BY ata.attr_no;
```

For types present through out the database (need to have special permissions):

```
SELECT dta.attr_name, dta.attr_type_name || CASE WHEN dta.length IS NOT NULL THEN '('||dta.length||')' ELSE NULL END 
  FROM dba_coll_types dct
  JOIN dba_type_attrs dta 
    ON dta.type_name = dct.elem_type_name AND dta.OWNER = dct.OWNER
 WHERE dct.type_name = 'COLLECTION_NAME'
   AND dct.OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME'
 ORDER BY dta.attr_no;
```

Comment: At first I though it won't work because I don't have the collection name, but I found a way to get the collection name using the object name.
Thanks allot for your help